# Missing PFX or certificate + private key

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, https

I have set the keys to node.js but still i am unable to get it to working.
  Can anybody tell me what should i do to make it work properly.
  I need to work with https with node.js.
    I get the following error.

```
   `tls.js:1127
    throw new Error('Missing PFX or certificate + private key.');
          ^
   Error: Missing PFX or certificate + private key.
    at Server (tls.js:1127:11)
    at new Server (https.js:35:14)
    at Object.exports.createServer (https.js:54:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/fusionmate/nodejs/server.js:4:36)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)`
```

Hers my code

```
    var
    app         = require('https').createServer(handler),
    io          = require('socket.io')(app),
    redis       = require('redis'),
    fs          = require('fs'),
    redisClient = redis.createClient();


     var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt')
    };
      app.createServer(options);
      app.listen(3000);

       console.log('Realtime Chat Server running at  http://127.0.0.1:3000/');

       function handler (req, res) {
       fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Error loading index.html');
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
      });
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. `options` needs to be passed to `https.createServer()` as the first argument (with `handler` being the optional second argument), but you're just passing in a request handler function. For example:

   ```
   var fs = require('fs');
   var options = {
     key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt')
   };
   var app = require('https').createServer(options, handler);
   // ...
   ```
2. Further down, you're calling `createServer()` on an `https.Server` (`app`) instance, which isn't correct (you've already created a server instance and instances don't have such a method).